# What does "esbenp" stand for in Prettier config in settings.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, formatter

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
```

I see `esbenp` a lot, but it's really hard to find what it stands for.

What does does it mean?

Answer (score 12):

[Esben Peterson](https://github.com/esbenp), he's the original developer of [Prettier for VS Code](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode), as can be seen [in the commit history](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/commit/ce0412fe987034df9ac786f7170f98c46bcbee9a).